# Clojure Midje 'provided' When Using 'pcalls'

Tags: clojure, midje

I'm reasonably new to Clojure, and am trying to parallelize some calls to a function.

Let's say I have a map as follows:

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```

and I want to use the keys and values as arguments of a function called my-function, with the function called for each key/value pair. I could use `doseq` as below:

```
(doseq [entry my-map] (my-function (key entry) (val entry)))
```

I then decide I want the calls to my-function to be in parallel (in my actual situation my-function will be making rest calls which are independent from each other, and so I want to do them in parallel). I came up with the following:

```
(apply pcalls (map #(partial my-function (key %) (val %)) my-map))
```

This seems to work as I expect (please correct me if I'm wrong or if there's a better way). The trouble I'm having now is getting my Midje tests to pass. They pass correctly if I use the `doseq` version above. In my tests, I am using (provided .... ) to ensure that the correct calls are made, and I wish to use this to check the calls to my-function. Is it possible to do this? I'm finding it hard to find much information on pcalls.

Thanks

--------- Edit ---------

I have contrived an example that demonstrates the failue.

The implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2c9214af3bb49d44495d),  and the tests [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8dcf82068f5691b71309). I have found that a single test runs fine, but multiple tests cause the following:

> FAIL at (pcalls_unit.clj:29) These calls were not made the right
>   number of times:
>       (my-func 2 2) [expected at least once, actually never called]
>
> FAIL "Test some pcalls 3" at (pcalls_unit.clj:26)
>       Expected: nil
>         Actual: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Error: You seem to have created a prerequisite for
>   pcalls-test.pcalls/my-func that interferes with that function's use in
>   Midje's own code. To fix, define a function of your own that uses
>   my-func, then describe that function in a provided clause.

Comment: What does your test look like? The problem might be that Midje is expecting the results to appear in a certain order.

Comment: Hi. My tests look something like:

(fact "test something"
    (method-that-calls-pcalls-stuff-and-more arg1 arg2 arg3) => {:status 200}
    (provided
        (my-function key1 val1) => some-result1
        (my-function key2 val2) => some-result2))

Comment: Can you link to a gist of a failing test? Please add the failure output.

Comment: Midje is supposed to require all lazy sequences to be fully evaluated (as with `doall`), but perhaps there's a bug. You could try wrapping the computation of the actual value with `doall`:

(fact     
  (doall (computation)) => expected     
  (provided ...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brian. I've wrapped the computation in doall but I get the same failures - (my-func arg1 arg2) [expected :times 1, actually called zero times] It is not always the same ones that appear, sometimes only 2 fail, sometimes 3, sometimes 4 etc. If I use doall and pmap as in Arthur's answer below, I get an error about my function interfering with that function's use in Midje's own code

Comment: Hi Brian, please see the edit to my question for some gists of an example

Answer (score 1):

To answer only the first part of the question `pmap` can also be used to write this:

```
(doall (pmap my-function (keys my-map) (vals my-map)))
```